# Does each docker container require the full disk space for required apps, or are they shared with containers on the same host?

Tags: docker

I would like to have separate images for each of my web apps on my VPS. For the sake of this questions, let's say I require a separate (L)AMP stack for each web app. Would each docker instance take up extra disk space for the same program?

i.e., 4 web apps = disk space required for 4 x apache, 4 x mysql, 4 x php? Or would the docker engine somehow handle the duplicated program requirements?